# Can I still ask my prospective advisor (guide) for a confirmation letter in the middle of Covid-19

Tags: phd, ethics, etiquette, funding, covid-19

I am a masters of mathematics student in Asia and I wrote to some professors for PH D position in number theory. One of the professors in France said yes to me but he said that I should look for other sources of funding as his university didn't had PhD funding at that time. There is one scholarship Foundation in my country where I was thinking of applying as a potential candidate. But the Conditions are that I should have a written appropval from my prospective guide.

In between I began preparing for my mid term exams and then appearing for them and masters dissertation viva . As I got spare time, the covid-19  outbreak spread. It's not to worry about here but I came to know through news that it's very serious in France and whole Europe. Also, last date for applying to scholarship portal is 31 March and it will not be extended.

> So , should I ask to my prospective guide to write a confirmation letter in the middle of Covid-19 in his country. Doesn't this show that I am an emotionless person with no etiquette at all who doesn't even care about in what situation my prospective guide, his family and his colleagues are?

Comment: I am really sorry for putting unrelated title. It was of another question I wanted to ask but found answer in related questions. Inconvenience caused is regretted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is fine to ask. Life goes on as best we can manage. The situation is worldwide, of course, and we don't yet see the end of it.

In a letter, you could, if you wish, say you are sorry if the request is coming at a bad time and that you understand the global situation.

You may not be able to get a reply in time, of course, or at all. But there is no problem asking. There is only a week left.

And note that people will want to start up as normal again as soon as the situation allows. Things may be delayed.

Comment: Could the downvoter.please explain?